# Difference Espacenet, European patent register and Patent scope

Tags: espacenet, european, patentscope

What is the difference between;
[Espacenet](https://worldwide.espacenet.com/),
[European patent register](https://www.epo.org/) and
[Patent scope](https://patentscope.wipo.int/)?

Answer (score 1):

[Espacenet](https://worldwide.espacenet.com/) (run by the [European Patent Office](https://www.epo.org/)) and [Patentscope](https://patentscope.wipo.int/) (run by [WIPO](http://www.wipo.int/)) are both databases through which you can search for patents and patent applications. I believe [Patentscope](https://patentscope.wipo.int/) has somewhat greater coverage. In this sense, they are both quite similar to Google Patents.

The [European register](https://www.epo.org/) is the legal register of all European patents and patent applications. It is primarily used for confirming the status of a European patent or application, and looking at the correspondence that occurred during prosecution.